# Timeline: Opportunistically Stacking Rectangles in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have an overlay of events on a graph. Events have duration in this case and are represented with rectagles:

[image]

Naively, each rectangle just gets dropped by the index of the event in array:

```
annotations.enter()
    .append("svg:a")
    .append('rect')
    .attr("y", (d, i) => { return i * ((height * .05) + 2) })
    .attr("height", height * .05)
    .attr("x", (d: any) => { return xScale(moment(d.StartDate).utc().unix() * 1000); })
    .attr("width", (d: any) => {
         var startT = moment(d.StartDate).utc().unix() * 1000
         var endT = moment(d.EndDate).utc().unix() * 1000
         if (startT == endT) {
             return 3
         }
         return xScale(endT) - xScale(startT)
    })
```

What I would like to do, is move events up towards the top, if there is space for the rectangle. However, I still want to stack them downward if there isn't space.

So the above would end up looking something like the following (I just edited the y vals in chrome inspector to make this image):
[image]

Any advice on how I might do this? The full D3 code for this in all its horror can be found at https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/blob/master/cmd/bosun/web/static/js/directives.ts#L486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following:

1. Sort By start Date
2. Track last end date for each row
3. Insert if current StartDate is greater than the Row's end date, if it isn't go to next row.

Code:

```
$scope.annotations = _.sortBy(data.Annotations, (d: Annotation) => { return d.StartDate; });
...
if (scope.annotateEnabled && scope.annotations.length != 0) {
    var rowId = {}; // annotation Id -> rowId
    var rowEndDate = {}; // rowId -> EndDate
    var maxRow = 0;    
    for (var i = 0; i < scope.annotations.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            rowId[scope.annotations[i].Id] = 0;
            rowEndDate[0] = scope.annotations[0].EndDate;
            continue;
        }
        for (var row = 0; row <= maxRow+1; row++) {
            if (row == maxRow+1) {
                rowId[scope.annotations[i].Id] = row;
                rowEndDate[row] = scope.annotations[i].EndDate;
                maxRow+=1
                break;
            }
            if (rowEndDate[row] < scope.annotations[i].StartDate) {
                rowId[scope.annotations[i].Id] = row;
                rowEndDate[row] = scope.annotations[i].EndDate;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
...
.attr("y", (d) => { return rowId[d.Id] * ((height * .05) + 2) })
```

Looks like the following:

[image]